# Cant get wheel scroll delta on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to get mouse wheel delta on Firefox browser.

I use javascript events listener to catch mouse wheel event. It works, but return not correct delta on Firefox, on Chrome every, works correct,

```
 element.on("DOMMouseScroll onwheel mousewheel onmousewheel wheel", function (e) {

                e = e || window.event;

                var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || e.originalEvent.detail;

                var delta2 = e.wheelDelta ? e.wheelDelta : -e.detail;

                console.log("delta", delta, delta2);
                //delta 0 NaN    <-- firefox
                //delta -120 NaN <-- chrome correct

                if (!doScroll(delta)) {
                    return;
                }

                var top = parseInt(element.css('top').replace('px', ''));
                element.css('top', top + delta);

                onScroll(delta);
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [WheelEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent), what you are looking for is called `deltaX`, `deltaY` and `deltaZ`.

There is no `wheelDelta` property, which belongs to an early draft chrome made called [`MouseWheelEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseWheelEvent) but which never made its way to the specs.

```js
document.onwheel = e => pre.textContent = e.deltaY;
```

```css
body{
  height: 600vh;
  }
pre{
  position: fixed;
  }
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```